# PayPal Express Checkout using the REST API

Tags: .net, rest, paypal

The only Express Checkout guide is what I found is [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/) however that is about definitely the 'classic' API

The official REST API docs are [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/) but it does not even mention the Express Checkout.

On github there is an official project with .NET bindings [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK) which is the REST API with cool samples. I've downloaded and have run it successfully, but not traces the Express Checkout in it.

Is is even possible to use express checkout with the REST API, or missed I something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, it's just "terminology" if you will. In the REST API, you have a `payment_method` named `paypal` (aka [Paypal Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/)) that pretty much maps to the classic "Express Checkout" flow.

One thing the Classic API has over REST at this time is the really cool [In-Context Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/).

Hth...

---

Here's an abbreviated working sample (ASP.Net MVC5) that may help (it's my "debug" site): http://code.edchavez.com/Pay/PayPal

- It should show you the flow as well as the data exchange.
- it's currently simulating *multiple captures* so the Captured amount is **less** than the total/authorized amount. Note: `is_final_capture: false`
- Use your sandbox account to test
- It uses the `Paypal .Net SDK Nuget Package v 1.5.0`

Hth.

Comment: EdSF: Thx this sounds as a relief. Btw In-Context Express Checkout is not available in my country. (why is this restriction, its an UI workflow thing which has no dependency on inter-state contracts or similars). Anyway, do you know any working UI workflow sample? The github link I've provided contains samples, but they are only simple API calls not in workflow.

Comment: @g.pickardou We have the same question (why in-context even has a country restriction given the backend is untouched) when I was helping a non-US merchant. The only answer I got was "working on it" - not really "why" :)

Comment: @g.pickardou As for the "sample" - yeah, but it's a local dev box. Any specific thing you have a question about? I can probably record a short video if you just want to see it in action...

Comment: Many thanks. First I am going to try to create a POC UI workflow using the REST API and my sandbox test app and users, which gives the same end user experience and functionality as the legacy API express checkout did. Then I'll be back with the results.

Comment: @g.pickardou updated answer with link to online working **debug** (sandbox) site (with notes)..Hth...